# Dynamic loading of mp3 files in AVAudioPlayer - Pass-by-value argument

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I am trying to play dynamically few mp3 sounds using AVAudioPlayer.

The following code works fine and indeed plays the sound,
nevertheless I get this error when Analyzing

**"Pass-by-value argument in message expression is undefined"**

Why so and how should one fix it?

```
+(void)playSound:(int)soundName
{
    NSString *theSound;
    switch (soundName) {
        case 1:
            theSound = @"beep1.mp3";
            break;
        case 2:
            theSound = @"beep2.mp3";
            break;
        case 3:
            theSound = @"beep3.mp3";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    //
    NSURL *s1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], theSound]];
    NSError *error;
    AVAudioPlayer *sound1;
    sound1 = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:s1 error:&error] autorelease];
    sound1.numberOfLoops = 0;
    //[sound1 prepareToPlay];
    [sound1 play];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want to try and play a sound file with no path if `soundName` is not 1,2 or 3?

For your default clause, either report an error, or just silently return. Don't create a player with an invalid path and ask to it to play it, it will only get upset.

Comment: Thank you Pete, I guess thats the other side of the problem / solution

Answer (score 0):

Try `NSString *theSound = @"";`

Setting a default value usually solves this problem.

Explanation:

The compiler is not sure that `theSound` will actually contain a value when it is used. It is good practice to assign default values to some objects, especially when dealing with loops and selection statements.

Comment: Hey Evan, it actually worked - thank you kindly. 
I would be grateful if you could explain in few words why is it so, I rather understand my errors than just fixing them.

Comment: The compiler is not sure that `theSound` will actually contain a value when it is used. It is good practice to assign default values to some objects, especially when dealing with loops and selection statements.